# Агрегировать результат find. MongoDB

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, find

У меня есть `find(fn)` который ищет по функции `fn` на JS нужные мне файлы.

Как мне агрегировать этот результат, можно ему присвоить какой-то айди или чтото такое?